# Multiple Distinct Popups on Single Page

Tags: jquery, html, popup

I'm trying to create a page which has several links and each link needs to popup its own text.

I got the code from some online forum and modified it to suit my template and popup content requirement and it worked just fine!... bust only for the first one. When I try to replicate the code for the second link, it opens up both popups together on clicking either link. I even switched the Javascript code from ID identifiers to class identifiers but nothing seems to be working.

Here's the Current code.

Javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
//open popup
$(".pop").click(function(){
  $(".overlay_form").fadeIn(1000);
  positionPopup();
});

//close popup
$(".close").click(function(){
    $(".overlay_form").fadeOut(500);
});
});

//position the popup at the center of the page
function positionPopup(){
  if(!$(".overlay_form").is(':visible')){
    return;
  } 
  $(".overlay_form").css({
      left: ($(window).width() - $('.overlay_form').width()) / 2,
      top: ($(window).width() - $('.overlay_form').width()) / 7,
      position:'absolute'
  });
}

//maintain the popup at center of the page when browser resized
$(window).bind('resize',positionPopup);
```

CSS:

```
<style>
.overlay_form{
    position: absolute;
    border: 5px solid gray;
    padding: 10px;
    background: white;
    width: 350px;
    height: auto;
}
.pop{
    display: text;
    width: 65px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
```

HTML Snippet:

```
<td height="117" colspan="6" align="left"><span class="stylearial">

<a href="#"> 
<span class="pop" id="pop1"><strong>Link Text 1</strong></span></a></span><br>

<form> <span class="overlay_form" id="form1" style="display:none">
                <p class="stylearial" align="center"><span class="stylecalibritext"> Heading </span></p>

                <p><span class="stylearial">Text 1...</span></p>
                <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none"><span class="close" id="close1"><p class="stylearial" align="center"><span class="stylecalibritext">Done</span></p></span></a>    
              </span>
</form>

              </td>



.
.
.



<td height="117" colspan="6" align="left">
<span class="stylearial">
<a href="#"><span class="pop" id="pop2"><strong>Link Text 2</strong></span></a></span><br>


<form><span class="overlay_form" id="form2" style="display:none">
                <p class="stylearial" align="center"><span class="stylecalibritext">Heading 2 </span></p>

                <p><span class="stylearial">
            Text 2...
            </span></p>
                <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none"><span class="close" id="close2"><p class="stylearial" align="center"><span class="stylecalibritext">Done</span></p></span></a>    
              </span></form>

              </td>
```

I'd appreciate if someone could help me out with this as I'm very new to jQuery. Let me know if you need any other information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up your markup a bit, you have a lot of extra tags you can probably condense even further - but this will just make it a bit easier to navigate. As for the popup, it does work but since you are referencing the overlay by its class name `.overlay_form`, and since there are **2** objects with that class name, it is going to display the last one it finds (always #2).

What you want to do is find the overlay *relative* to the `.pop` span you are clicking on. In my sample fiddle this is done by navigating to the `parent()` (`<td>`) and then finding the `form .overlay_form` item within that parent.

```
$(".pop").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find("form .overlay_form").fadeIn(1000);
    positionPopup();
});
```

[Here is a fiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/xfC8e/)

This would also prevent you from having to hardcode in which popup you want to show.

Comment: The JS Fiddle is working as I want it to... But I replicated the code on my website and the same problem persists... I noticed that you've used jQuery 2.0.2... I'm using jQuery 1.6.1.min.js... Can that be an issue?

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue. Check to see what `$(this).parent().find("form .overlay_form")` is returning to make sure it is pointing to the correct object - if it's not then you likely have the markup layed out differently than the fiddle. Also check to see if you have any errors in the console and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

In your open and close functions you are specifying CSS classes rather than ID. Right now you are saying any object with CSS class overlay_form. What you need to do is replace

```
$(".overlay_form").fadeIn(1000);
```

with

```
$("#pop1").fadeIn(1000);
```

I would then suggest adding the onclick event to the buttons that cause a pop up EX:

```
<span class="pop" id="pop1" onclick="openPop('pop1');"><strong>Link Text 1</strong></span>
```

Now your JavaScript function will be:

```
function openPop(id){
    var controlId = '#' + id;
    $(controlId).fadeIn(1000);
    positionPopup();
}
```

This should work for you although it is off the top of my head and I haven't tested.

In the future I would recommend looking into [jQuery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) as you can make it work exactly as you want it and it is set to pop up in the middle of the screen and includes the close buttons and all that other fun stuff.